# How to change a HTML table data value after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a form.

`<form action="form.php" method="POST" name="form1" id="f1">`

On this form is an input for a name.

`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="n1" placeholder="Name" required>`

The user inputs their name and clicks submit, the form.php then kicks in and this name is emailed to an email address.

`$name = $_POST['n1'];`

If this is successful the user is redirected to another page via;

`header("Location: /anotherpage.html");`

Up to this point everything works fine.

On this page is a HTML table with a table data cell;

`<td id="table1"></td>`

**Q. What I am trying to do is when the user is redirected to this page the name they submit appears in the tables data cell.**

I have tried a couple of things with no success.

On the HTML side;

`value="<?php echo $name;?>"` & `value="<?php echo $_POST['n1'];?>"` within the td tag.

`<?php echo $name;?>` & `<?php echo $_POST['n1'];?>` between the td tags.

& on the PHP side after the redirect header;

`getElementById('n1').value = $name;`

`getElementById('n1').value = $_POST['n1'];`

Is there a way of doing this?

Look forward to hearing from anyone

Kind Regards

Comment: Do you have any intermediate data storage? such as Database or may be Plain Session, or perhaps localstorage of browser

Comment: Does the other page need to be html, if it is php use the $_POST global variable you submitted with the form. Then get the value out of the $_POST and echo out your div with the value in the data cell. You could also send the data over via the redirect as a key/value pair over the url.

Comment: No database, user submits form and details are entered into email message with PHP which is then sent on to an email address.

Comment: `header("Location: /anotherpage.html?name=$name"`)

Comment: @dalelandry cheers for this unfortunately it did not work however I am working on this locally and not live, would it be for this reason that this is not working?

Comment: See my answer with explanation. I tested on my local server as well. Provided the parameters are located in the URL, the `URLSearchParams` and `.get()` will get the parameters values.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the name over the **url** using the ***header*** using **PHP**...

```php
// check the submission of your form using the name set in the submit button...
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // DO NOT SKIP ON SANITIZING YOUR INPUTS!!!!!
    // This example is very basic, I am not showing how to sanitize inputs
    $fname = filter_var(strip_tags($_POST['fname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $lname = filter_var(strip_tags($_POST['lname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    // do your email stuff
    // after you have done all your other code, send the name 
    // key/value pair over the url using the header...
    header("Location: someotherpage.html?fname=".fname ."&lname=".lname);
}
```

Once you have sent the values over the url to the `someotherpage.html` page you can use `URLSearchParams` to search the url for `key` parameters to get their paired value/s. `window.location.search` => ***The query string portion of the URL. This includes the question mark, and everything following.*** Use `.get()` to get the url's parameters using their *key*. Then you can assign them using javascript with the `dataset` attribute => `element.dataset.fname = firstName`.

```js
let parameters = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let firstName = parameters.get('fname');
let lastName = parameters.get('lname');

let div = document.getElementById('data');

div.dataset.fname = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
```

Returns the following on ***someotherpage.html* :**

[image: dataset attribute html]